# How Do I Add Custom Fields to Products for Product Comparison in Big Commerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Our BigCommerce website allows customers to compare two or more products and see their comparative prices and descriptions

We would like customers to be able to also compare other product attributes such as size, thickness, grit specification, etc. At present these attributes are just listed in the product description, but we would like to be able to add them to the product as attributes, and then have them show up in the comparison page.

See this screenshot for an example: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B259JW32ACNsOFFaR0ZWVVFOVEk/edit?usp=drivesdk

Question:
1. How do we add special attributes to products such as size, thickness etc (note, these are not product options, just product characteristics)
2. How would we then display these attributes in a comparison page ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add those attributes as custom fields they'll display neatly on your product comparison page; they won't be separate rows but I know that our theme, by default, displays custom fields as:

**Custom Field Name**
Custom Field Text

**Custom Field Name**
Custom Field Text

Comment: Thanks very much - I hadn't found the 'custom fields' tab on the product description form! Now that I have that it is working great and OK for our purposes with the theme we are using.